# Force a new line of text in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I've made a foreach loop for names, job titles and emails from the database.
Because of my padding, and due to some names being longer than others it forces it to a new line. How can I make this automatically push down the last word in the column, e.g (Firstname Lastname) to a new line whenever there's a space inside the name? So that Lastname will be pushed down to a new line. I have both First name and Last name in one column called 'name'. Is there an easy CSS fix for this?

HTML/BLADE:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach ($users as $user)
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="ama-roster">
        <img class="img-circle img-rounded" src="{{ $user->avatar }}" />
          <div class="ama-roster-content">
            <h4>{{ $user->name }}</h4>
            <p>{{ $user->jobTitle}}</p>
            <p>{{ $user->email }}</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .ama-roster {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  }

.ama-roster-content {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.ama-roster img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.ama-roster-content p {
  line-height: 0.5;
}

.ama-roster-content h4 {
  color: #274260;
}
```

Currently it looks like this:

```css
.ama-roster {
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ama-roster-content {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.ama-roster img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 0;
}

.ama-roster-content p {
  line-height: 0.5;
}

.ama-roster-content h4 {
  color: #274260;
}
```

```html
<div class="ama-roster">
            <img class="img-circle img-rounded" src="http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Original-Facebook-Geek-Profile-Avatar-6.jpg" />
              <div class="ama-roster-content">
                <h4>First <br>Name</h4>
                <p>Boss</p>
                <p>firstname@mail.com</p>
              </div>
</div>

<div class="ama-roster">
            <img class="img-circle img-rounded" src="http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Original-Facebook-Geek-Profile-Avatar-6.jpg" />
              <div class="ama-roster-content">
                <h4>First Name</h4>
                <p>Boss</p>
                <p>firstname@mail.com</p>
              </div>
</div>

<div class="ama-roster">
            <img class="img-circle img-rounded" src="http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Original-Facebook-Geek-Profile-Avatar-6.jpg" />
              <div class="ama-roster-content">
                <h4>First <br>Name</h4>
                <p>Boss</p>
                <p>firstname@mail.com</p>
              </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .ama-roster-conten{width: 30px;} or some other value?

Comment: Thanks, worked! Haha. I'm so dumb.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `width: 50%;` to the h4 tag class.